# Linked Lists getNext() and while(next!= null ); problem

Tags: java, linked-list

I am fairly new to java and was hoping that someone would be able to help me. I am trying to create a linked list to compare the winning numbers and the players numbers as you are able to buy more than one ticket using a different name in my Lottery Program. The program works but it only outputs the results of the last ticket and not all of them. It has to do with my code in the matches() method but I'm unsure on how to output everyone's tickets results when draw numbers is clicked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LOTTERY
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    private PLAYER pHead;

    WINNINGNUMBERS win = new WINNINGNUMBERS();

    public LOTTERY()
    {
        pHead = null;
    }

    public void welcome() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Welcome to the Lottery Game. Press Ok to Continue", "Lottery Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    public void StartUpmenu() {


        Object[] options = {"Quit",
                "How To Play",
                "Buy Ticket"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Please select one of the following buttons: ","Lottery Game",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[2]);

        if (n == 0) {
            exitOptions();
        } else if (n == 1) {
            rules();
        } else if (n == 2) {
            enterPlayerDetails();
            numOptionMenu();
            displayPlayers();
        }
    }

    public void rules() {
        System.out.println("How To Play The Lottery Game:" + "\n" + "\n" +
            "1. Enter Your Name" +  "\n" + "2. Select 6 Of Your Own Numbers or Choose A Lucky Dip." 
            + "\n" + "3. The Money You Win Will Be Revealed Based On The Amount Of Numbers You Matched" + "\n" + "\n" +
            "1 Number - £2" + "\n" + "2 Numbers - £10" + "\n" + "3 Numbers - £30" + "\n" + 
            "4 Numbers - £140" + "\n" + "5 Numbers - £1,750" + "\n" + "6 Numbers - £1 million");

        StartUpmenu();
    }

    public void enterPlayerDetails() {
        PLAYER pNext; 
        System.out.println("Enter your Name : ");
        String vName = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("What age are you?");
        int vAge = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        while (vAge < 16) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, You have entered an invalid age. You must be 16 or above");
            vAge = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        pNext = new PLAYER(vName,vAge,pHead);
        pHead = pNext;
    }

    public void numOptionMenu() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        Object[] options = { "Choose Your Own",
                "Lucky Dip"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Please select one of the following buttons: ","Lottery Game",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[1]);

        if (n == 0) {
            currentPlayer.choose();
        } else if (n == 1) {
            currentPlayer.luckyDip();
        }
    }

    public void drawNumbersMenu() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        Object[] options = { "Quit",
                "Draw Numbers", 
                "Buy Another Ticket"};
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Please select one of the following buttons: ","Lottery Game",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[2]);

        if (n == 0) {
            exitOptions();
        } else if (n == 1) {
            displayWinningNumbers();
            matches();
            playAgainMenu();
        } else if (n == 2) {
            enterPlayerDetails();
            numOptionMenu();
            displayPlayers();
            drawNumbersMenu();
        }
    }

    public void playAgainMenu() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        Object[] options = { "Quit",
                "Play Again"
            };
        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Please select one of the following buttons: ","Lottery Game",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[1]);

        if (n == 0) {
            exitOptions();
        } else if (n == 1) {
            runProg();
        }
    }

    public void displayPlayers() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        System.out.println("Name: " + currentPlayer.getName());
        System.out.println("Age: " + currentPlayer.getAge());
        currentPlayer.luckyDip();
        currentPlayer.bubbleSort();
        System.out.println("Your Numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(currentPlayer.getNumbers(i));
        }
    }

    public void displayWinningNumbers() {
        win.winningNumbers();
        win.bubbleSort();
        System.out.println("Winning Numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println(win.getWinningNumbers(i));
        }
    }

    public void matches() {
        PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
        PLAYER pNext; 
        
        do{
            int count = 0; 
            PLAYER next = pNext;
            for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j< 6; j++) {
                    if (win.getWinningNumbers(j) == next.getNumbers(i)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                System.out.println("Unlucky " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you haven't won anything");
            }
            else if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won £2");
            }
            else if (count == 2) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won £10");
            }
            else if (count == 3) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won £30");
            }
            else if (count == 4) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won £140");
            }
            else if (count == 5) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won £1,750");
            }
            else if (count == 6) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + currentPlayer.getName() + " you have won the jackpot of £1 million !!!");
            }
            
            next = next.getNext();
            
        } while(next!= null );
    }
    

    public void exitOptions()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for Playing!", "End Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0); 
    }

    public void runProg() {
        welcome();
        StartUpmenu();
        drawNumbersMenu();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOTTERY lottery = new LOTTERY();
        lottery.runProg();
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PLAYER
{
    private String vName;
    private PLAYER pNext;
    private int vAge;
    private int numbers[];

    public PLAYER(String n, int a, PLAYER p)
    {
        vName = n;
        pNext = p;
        vAge = a;
        numbers = new int[6];
        Random random = new Random();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return vName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return vAge;
    }

    public int getNumbers(int i){
        return numbers[i];
    }
    
    public int getNext(int next) {
      return next;
   }
    
    public void luckyDip() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Integer (i));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = (list.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void choose() {
       
    }

    public void bubbleSort() {
       
        for(int a = numbers.length; a > 0; a--){
            for(int i = 0; i < a-1; i++) {
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
                    int temp = numbers[i+1];
                    numbers[i+1] = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WINNINGNUMBERS
{
    private int wNumbers[];

    public WINNINGNUMBERS() {
      wNumbers = new int[6];
      Random ran = new Random();
    }
    
    public void setWinningNumbers(int [] wNumbers){
        this.wNumbers = wNumbers;
    }

    public int getWinningNumbers(int i){
        return wNumbers[i];
    }
    
    public void winningNumbers() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
        {
            list.add(new Integer (i));
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            wNumbers[i] = (list.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public void bubbleSort() {
         for(int a = wNumbers.length; a > 0; a--){
            for(int i = 0; i < a-1; i++) {
                if(wNumbers[i] > wNumbers[i+1]) {
                    int temp = wNumbers[i+1];
                    wNumbers[i+1] = wNumbers[i];
                    wNumbers[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        setWinningNumbers(wNumbers);
    }
}

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Your getNext function inside PLAYER returns an integer and requires an integer parameter, but you are assigning it to a PLAYER object with no parameter inside your matches() at `next = next.getNext();`

Comment: I don't see any code for a `linked list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your getNext function inside PLAYER so it returns a player object than can be assigned to next inside your matches() function in Lottery.

Currently it has an integer parameter and returns an integer, but you use it as 
`next = next.getNext()` in your matches().

I think this is what you want instead

```
public PLAYER getNext() {
      return pNext;
}
```

Edit:
I omitted the if statements for simplicity.

```
public void matches() {
    PLAYER currentPlayer = pHead;
 // PLAYER pNext; remove this, since you are not using pNext in the if statments

    do{
        int count = 0; 
   //   PLAYER next = pNext; also remove this for the same reason
        for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j< 6; j++) {
                //check the winning numbers in currentPlayer instead of a null object pNext
                if (win.getWinningNumbers(j) == currentPlayer.getNumbers(i)) { 
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // next = next.getNext(); remove for the same reason as above
        // since you are using currentPlayer to check if the player wins, you shouldto modify current player
        currentPlayer = currentPlayer.getNext(); 
        } while(currentPlayer != null ); //check if currentPlayer is not null
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the only thing is the 'PLAYER next = pNext;' and the 'while(next!= null );' in the matches method says the variable 'next' and 'pNext' can't be found. I can't seem to find how this is.

Comment: in your do while loop you assign pNext to a PLAYER object called next, but you never instantiated pNext. Also, throughout the loop you are using pHead, which you never modified in the loop, so you are going to use the same pHead in every loop

Comment: I'd like to hear what is your logic for the do while loop, because I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to output the results for all the ticket number matches by comparing it to the winning numbers. If I enter more than one ticket, it will only output the last ticket result and not all of them. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much for your help and explanations.